# Why am I losing my object reference when I pass from a .forEach?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a question about passing by reference. In particular I am passing `wf` to wordFormUpdateSubmit.

- When I do this: `wf = response.data;` it does not change anything in word.wordForms
- When I do this: `self.word.wordForms[key] = response.data;` it correctly changes the contents of wf in word.wordForms

My question is why is it not passing by reference and why does `wf = response.data;` not work?

```
 wordFormCheckAndUpdate = (): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var self = this;
    var promises = [];
    angular.forEach(self.word.wordForms, function (wf, key) {
        var updatePromise = self.wordFormUpdateSubmit(wf, key);
        promises.push(updatePromise);         
    });
    return self.$q.all(promises);
 };

  wordFormUpdateSubmit = (wf: IWordForm, key: number): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var self = this;
    return self.$http({
        url: self.ac.dataServer + "/api/WordForm/Put",
        method: "PUT",
        data: wf
    })
        .then(
        (any => {
            // This does not correctly populate self.word.wordForms[0]
            wf = response.data;

            // This works
            self.word.wordForms[key] = response.data;


        });
   }
```

Comment: One thing's for sure: This isn't Javascript. C#, maybe?

Comment: @JanDvorak Either Typescript or Babel's type system, both are JavaScript supersets.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher ... and the types are from angular?

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm guessing. I don't use angular myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript does not have pass-by-reference, it has "[call by sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing)".

If you assign a new value to a function parameter, it will not make any change to the original value passed into the function. It will just overwrite the parameter.

This should be a viable (and cleaner) alternative for what you are trying to do:

```
wordFormCheckAndUpdate = (): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var self = this;

    return self.$q.all(self.word.wordForms.map((wf, key) =>
        self.wordFormUpdateSubmit(wf, key)
    ))
    .then(function (values) {
        self.word.wordForms = values;
    });
};

wordFormUpdateSubmit = (wf: IWordForm, key: number): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var self = this;
    return self.$http({
        url: self.ac.dataServer + "/api/WordForm/Put",
        method: "PUT",
        data: wf
    })
    .then(response => response.data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Will accept answer after 10 mins.  Solved my problem.